# How do you print first two columns with slashes?

Tags: shell

I have a folder path that looks like this:

```
"/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD\ 1/Users/mike"
```

I would like to only print out the first two columns with the slashes and omit the everything past that:

```
"/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD\ 1/"
```

I can print out the first two columns with awk but it removes the "/"'s.

Comment: why not `awk '{sub(/Users.*$/,"",$0);print}' file`. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using quotes and backslashes is redundant, just use quotes:

```
$ path="/Volumes/Macintosh HD 1/Users/mike"
$ grandparent="$(dirname "$(dirname "$path")")"
$ echo "$grandparent"
/Volumes/Macintosh HD 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cut`:

```
echo "$path" | cut -d/ -f1-3
```